# Ошибка: несколько объявлений одной переменной

Tags: c++, linux, c

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пишет что по разному была объявлена переменная Init.
Вот тут я её объявил :

```
#ifndef LIB_H

#define LIB_H


#include <stdio.h>

#include "stack.h"



void addProcess(struct Cell **);

void deleteOneProcess(struct ProcessInfo);

void deleteAll(struct Cell **);

void Init(struct ProcessInfo*);


int get_button();



#endif
```

а вот тут вызвал:

```
void Init()
{
    key_t key = ftok("main.c", 228);
    int SemID = semget(key,1,0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    semctl(SemID, 0, SETVAL,0);
}
```

как её можно исправить ?

Comment: Нет, пишет что объявление не соответствует реализации. с аргументами Init(strcut ...)  и без Init() - добавьте аргументы

Comment: Ну так, как уже было сказано ранее: почему у вас объявление функции Init не совпадает с определением? И почему ваш вопрос озаглавлен "несколько объявлений одной переменной"? Где вы такое увидели?

Answer (score 3):

У вас реализация и прототип функции не совпадают.  В прототипе указан аргумент struct ProcessInfo*, а в реализации его уже нет.

Answer (score 2):

Сообщение об ошибке достаточно ясное

> number of arguments does't match prototype

а именно

> число аргументов не соответствует прототипу функции

То есть вы вызываете функцию, не передавая ей ни один аргумент, в то время как функция объявлена, как имеющая один параметр

```
void Init(struct ProcessInfo*);
```

Более того далее вы определяете эту функцию уже без параметра

```
void Init()
{
    key_t key = ftok("main.c", 228);
    int SemID = semget(key,1,0666 | IPC_CREAT);
    semctl(SemID, 0, SETVAL,0);
}
```

Кстати сказать, это не вызов функции, а ее определение. Вызываете функцию вы в каком-то другом месте (signals_lin.c: 77:1).

Вам надо согласовать объявление этой функции с ее определением (либо функция имеет параметр, и должна быть вызвана с соответствующим аргументом, либо не имеет параметра, и должна быть вызвана без аргумента).

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка совсем в другом. Функция `Init()` в качестве аргумента ожидает `struct ProcessInfo*`, но не получает ничего. Измените

```
void Init(struct ProcessInfo*);
```

на

```
void Init();
```

(все равно `ProcessInfo*` в функции не используется).